# how to get listbox value in another php page

Tags: php, post, listbox, html

i think i am doing some mistake in my code. can someone please correct me. how to get the list box values in another page.

```
print "<form method=\"post\" action=\"fetch_test.php\">";
print "Report From: ";
print "<select name=fromdate[]>";
print "<option selected=\"selected\">Date</option>";
print "<option value=01>01</option>";
print "<option value=02>02</option>";
print "<option value=03>03</option>";
print "</select>";

print "<select name=frommonth[]>";
print "<option selected=\"selected\">Month</option>";
print "<option value=jan>Jan</option>";
print "<option value=feb>Feb</option>";
print "<option value=mar>Mar</option>";
print "</select>";

print "<br><br>";
print "<input type=submit>";
print "</form>";
```

fetch_test.php contains below code.

```
<?php
print $_POST['fromdate'];
print $_POST['frommonth'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the name as an `Array`.

Fixed code:

```
print "<form method=\"post\" action=\"fetch_test.php\">";
print "Report From: ";
print "<select name=fromdate>";
print "<option selected=\"selected\">Date</option>";
print "<option value=01>01</option>";
print "<option value=02>02</option>";
print "<option value=03>03</option>";
print "</select>";

print "<select name=frommonth>";
print "<option selected=\"selected\">Month</option>";
print "<option value=jan>Jan</option>";
print "<option value=feb>Feb</option>";
print "<option value=mar>Mar</option>";
print "</select>";

print "<br><br>";
print "<input type=submit>";
print "</form>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You stored it in an array, so call it in an array also.

```
<?php

print $_POST['fromdate'][$yournumbervalue];
print $_POST['frommonth'][$yournumbervalue];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting your `select` tag names, you want to have `<select name="fromdate[]">` to get an array, and you want to use `<select from="fromdate">` to get a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are more than one `name='fromdate'` or `name='frommonth'`, you don't need the `[]`.

Just try normal:

```
print "<select name='fromdate'>";
```

Make sure you put `'` around the name attribute!

Then use:

```
$_POST['fromdate'];
```

At the moment you're putting it into an array, so if you want to keep it the way it is, use:

```
foreach ($fromdate as $date){
  echo $date;
}
```